# Let $f $ a function of class $C^2$ that has a local maximum, prove that exists $ k$ such that $f(x,y) + k(x^2 + y^2)$ has a minimum

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, vector-analysis

> Let $f : R^2 → R$ a function of class $C^2$ near to $(0,0)$. If it is known by  the second derivative test that f(x,y) has a local maximum in $(0,0)$,  show that exists some $ k \in R$ such that $g(x,y) = f(x,y) + k(x^2 + y^2)$ has a local minimum in $(0,0)$

My approach:

$H f(0,0) = $ $\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(0,0)& \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}(0,0)\\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(0,0)& \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(0,0) 
\end{bmatrix}$ and due to $f$ is of class $C^2$ then $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}$

then we can write $Hf(0,0)= \begin{bmatrix}
a& b \\
b& c 
\end{bmatrix}$

If $f$ has a local maximum then the quadratic form definited by to $Hf$ is  negative definite i.e., $ax^2 +2bxy+cy^2 <0$

On the other hand, $Hg(0,0)= \begin{bmatrix}
a+2k& b \\
b& c+2k 
\end{bmatrix}$ and in order to prove that $g$ has a minimum we must show that exists some $k$ such that $(a+2k)x^2 +2bxy+(c+2k)y^2 >0$

I'm stuck here, don't know how can I compute $k$. Is it right or is there another way to solve it?

Comment: Hint: Think about the relation between eigenvalues of $Hf(0,0)$ and $Hg(0,0)$

Comment: Will it work if  i set $k=-\frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2} 2$ where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $Hf$?

Comment: That should work. In fact, any $k$ strictly larger than $\frac{\max(|\lambda_1|,|\lambda_2|)}{2}$ works.